# Convert a list to dataframe in python jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have a lists name 'val' which is below:

```
[       x  y
0      0.0 A
1      1.0 B
2      2.0 C
3      3.0 D
4      4.0 E
5      5.0 F]
```

I need to convert this to a pandas dataframe where i'm failing.

the code i used is:

df = pd.DataFrame(val)

The output which i'm getting is:

```
0
x y 0.0 A 1.0 B 2.0 C 3.0 D 4.0 E 5.0 F
```

The Expected output:

```
 x   y
0.0  A
1.0  B
2.0  C
3.0  D
4.0  E
5.0  F
```

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: How working `df = pd.DataFrame(val[0])` ?

Comment: Can you please show the list "val" in a correct format?

Comment: Thank you!! @jezrael it's fine now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is `DataFrame` in list, so need select first value in list by indexing:

```
df = val[0]
```

If need join all values together:

```
df1 = pd.concat(val, ignore_index=True)
```

Or:

```
df2 = pd.concat(val, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: I have more value like val[0],val[1],val[2] how can i proceed with that output. Now i'm confused @jezrael